# How to revert to the home page of the app when user reloaded the browser refresh button?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-refresh

```
  const confirmExit = (e) => {
      let dialogText = 'You have unsaved changes. If you leave this page all changes will be lost. Do you wish to continue?';
      e.returnValue = dialogText;
      return dialogText;
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

How to add a condition once the user confirmed the reload option so that i can route to the root page of the app?

before: http://localhost:9000/test

After the user confirmed the refresh button: http://localhost:9000/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using window.location.href="your-redirected-url-here";
However- if you do not want the user to go back to the earlier page, then try this:
 window.location.replac="your-redirected-url-here";
this will remove the earlier page from the history.

Comment: how do I know that the user doesn't want to reload the refresh when he clicked don't reload in the prompt box?

Comment: Don't invoke the method on that button? Wrap the location replace code in a function, and run it only when the user clicks the reload button

Comment: how to know whether the user selected reload button in prompt box?

Comment: Use the onbeforeunload event.

Comment: Using window.onbeforeunload will allow you to catch back button or refresh events. Then in the function where you use these handler, you can issue a prompt.

Comment: window.location.href is not working inside the window.onbeforeunload handler.

Comment: I'll have to test it myself. Accept the answer and close the question, I'll update you when I test it.